# onTouch method - Keeping up with which instances of the button have been clicked or pressed

Tags: java, android, touch-event, ontouchlistener, android-button

I have a loop where i am created multiple button instances and with each instance they have a TouchListener. However, i am having trouble figuring out how to manage when the different buttons have been touched. What i am trying to accomplish is that each button represents a textview and when i touch the button i want to add that particular textview associated with that instance of the button to an arraylist. However, when the same button is touched again, i want to remove it from the list..and add it back again if it is touched again. Oh yeah addToOrder currently is global and initialized to true.

Thoughts?

EDIT****per my comments below button is now an instance of a subclass of Button that I wrote so that i can easily keep up with each instance of the button. That solved the issue.

here is the code:

```
 button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getActionMasked();
        //Log.d("Touched Add To Order Button with id of ", button.getId() + ": " + button.getText().toString());
        TextView relativeTitleView;
        ViewGroup relativeGroup = (ViewGroup)v.getParent();
        relativeTitleView = (TextView) relativeGroup.getChildAt(0);
        //Log.d("Add To Order Button Touched", relativeTitleView.getText().toString());

           /*if(action ==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){                          
            addToOrder = (addToOrder) ? true : false;
            if(addToOrder)
                dbAccess.addToOrder(relativeTitleView.getText().toString());
            else
                dbAccess.removeFromOrder(relativeTitleView.getText().toString());
            }
           else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                addToOrder = !addToOrder;

            }*/

           if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
              if(button.getTouchInfo()){
               dbAccess.addToOrder(relativeTitleView.getText().toString());
               button.setTouchInfo(false);
              }
              else {
                dbAccess.removeFromOrder(relativeTitleView.getText().toString());
                button.setTouchInfo(true);
              }
         }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: i just realized that addToOrder - since being global is going to make it impossible to tell whether a certain instance of a button has been touched or not. what i need is an addToOrder variable for EACH button instance - however i am going to get that dreadful final/non-final variable error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the only way items are added/removed from dbAccess, you can just switch based on whether or not it's already there.

```
if(dbAccess.contains(relativeTitleView.getText().toString())
   dbAccess.removeFromOrder(relativeTitleView.getText().toString());
else
   dbAccess.addToOrder(relativeTitleView.getText().toString());
```

Edit: Assuming dbAccess has a contains(), can't tell what type it is here.

Comment: dbAccess is actually a class that i have written to be a mediator between my Activities and my model(database). trying to go with the MVC as much as possible. I actually fixed the problem. I created a custom button class that extends the button class with a private boolean variable and created 2 functions that takes a boolean and returns a boolean, namely setTouchInfo(boolean clicky) and getTouchInfo() which returns the status of the button(whether it has been clicked or not). I will comment out the old code and post the new code. Should have thought about this before.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an arbitrary object on any `View` (of which Button is a subclass) using `setTag`, of which there are two versions.

So, for example, in your loop used to create each `Button` you could add a `String` instance or an `Integer` instance to the `Button` using `myButton.setTag(Object o)`

When the button is touched, it gets passed in to `onTouch` as the `View v` argument.

Simply pull the tag from `v` using `getTag()` and examine it.

Comment: yep that was the idea as i just solved - i didnt set tags i just used a private variable within the subclass to keep up with what state the button was in. see new code and edit comment at the end of the question

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would use a Switch or ToggleButton rather than an ordinary button.  That way the button keeps track of the two states you are interested in.  The setOnCheckedChanged listener would get a callback when the switch was toggled.

Second I would create a named class derived from OnCheckedChangeListener rather than using an anonymous class.

A constructor in your named class could link the listener to the appropriate text view by setting a member which could be used in the listener's callback method.

To make this more concrete:

```
private MyListener implements CheckedChangeListener{
  private TextView textView;
  MyListener(TextView textView){
    this.textView = textView;
  }
  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
    String text = textView.getText().toString();
    if(isChecked){
      dbAccess.addToOrder(text);
    }else{
      dbAccess.removeFromOrder(text);
    }
  }
// then later....
button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MyListener(theCorrespondingTextView));
```

Answer (score 0):

per my comments below button is now an instance of a subclass of Button that I wrote so that i can easily keep up with each instance of the button. That solved the issue.